# Integration of $\sec^4 x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

While practicing for the AP exam, I came across an integral that I found interesting and I attempted to do by hand: $$\int(\sec^4 x)\, dx$$
Eventually I got stuck, but here are the steps I took-
$$\int(\sec^4 x) \,dx$$
$$\int(\sec^2 x)(\sec x)(\sec x)\,dx$$ 
$$\int(\sec^2 x)(\sec x) (\frac{\tan x}{\sin x})\,dx$$
$$\int(\csc x)(\sec^2 x)(\sec x \tan x)\,dx $$
Apply Integration by parts
$$(u=\csc x, dv=\sec^2 x(\sec x\tan x)$$
$$\frac{\sec^3 x}{3\sin x} + \int(\frac{\sec^3 x}{3})(\csc x \cot x) \,dx$$
$$\frac{\sec^3 x}{3\sin x} + {1\over 3}\int(\sec^2 x)(\csc^2 x) \,dx$$
Here is where I get stuck.. I appreciate any help you can offer on where to go from here!

Answer (score 9):

$I=\displaystyle\int\sec^4(x)\,dx$

$I =\displaystyle\int \sec^2(x)(1+\tan^2(x))\,dx$

$u=\tan(x)\implies \sec^2(x)\,dx =\,du$

$I = \displaystyle\int1+u^2\,du$

$I = u+\frac{u^3}3+C$

$I = \tan(x)+\frac{\tan^3(x)}3+C$

Answer (score 9):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan x=\sec^2x.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tan^3 x=3\sec^2x\tan^2x=3\sec^4x-3\sec^2x.$$
So
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\tan^3 x+3\tan x)=3\sec^4x.$$

Answer (score 4):

As noted [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_secant_cubed), we can integrate powers of secant with integration by parts, viz. $$\int\sec^{n+2}x\,dx=\sec^n x\tan x-n\int\sec^n x\tan^2 x \, dx = \frac{\sec^n x \tan x+n \int\sec^n x \, dx}{n+1}.$$This recursion allows us to go from $\int\sec^2 x \,dx=\tan x + C$ to $$\int\sec^4 x \,dx = \frac{\sec^2 x \tan x + 2\tan x}{3}+C.$$

Comment: I edited this in order to put a small space before each instance of $dx.$ But I also saw numerous instances of \mathrm{sec}. Using that instead of \sec fails to result in proper spacing in things like $3\sec x,$ where you see instead $3\mathrm{sec} x.$ So I changed those. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks. Sorry about sec. I got into a bad habit because, it seems, such a workaround is necessary for the hyperbolic secant.

Comment: You should also not use \mathrm{} for the hyperbolic secant either. Instead, write \operatorname{sech}. The difference between \mathrm{sech} and \operatorname{sech} is seen here: $$ \begin{align} \text{3\mathrm{sech}x}: & \qquad 3\mathrm{sech}x \\ \text{3\operatorname{sech}x}: & \qquad 3\operatorname{sech}x \\ \text{3\operatorname{sech}(x)}: & \qquad 3\operatorname{sech}(x) \end{align} $$ You see that proper spacing is not present with \mathrm{} and with \operatorname{} the space to the right  and left of $\operatorname{sech}$ depends on the context.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks for that insight.

Comment: In actual LaTeX (as opposed to MathJax, which is used here), before the \begin{doucument} statement, you can add this statement: \newcommand{\sech}{\operatorname{sech}}. Or, if you like, \newcommand{\s}{\operatorname{sech}}. Then use the newly created command after the \begin{document} wherever the occasion arises, and proper spacing will result.

Comment: Let's see if this works in comments. $\quad \newcommand{\s}{\operatorname{sech}} \quad$ $\longleftarrow$ Invisible code here. $$ y = 3\s x $$ The displayed line above is coded as y = 3\s x . That doesn't work without the foregoing invisible code. Right-click on the invisible code and choose "show math as" and then "TeX Commands", and do the same with the visibly displayed line and you'll see everything.

Comment: @MichaelHardy \newcommand did wonders in my thesis. I wasn't able to see your invisible code, though.

Comment: Put the mouse cursor exactly in the center of it and right-click. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Yes, I know how to make a clickable Tex Commands option appear; it's just that clicking it doesn't do anything, at least not in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, this is quasi immediate.

$$\int\sec^4x\,dx=\int(\tan^2x+1)\,d\tan x=\frac13\tan^3x+\tan x.$$

Comment: thanks for dripping on me as a high schooler. you inspired me to get an advanced math education

Comment: @MikeH: not being an English native, I cannot fully appreciate the salt in your comment.

Comment: actually no salt, I was (mostly) genuine! I just thought it was funny looking back. “dripping on me” in this case means elegantly solving it in a way completely over my head :)

Comment: @MikeH: thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is a little long.
How about $\sec^4x=(\sec^2x)(\sec^2x)=\sec^2x(\tan^2x+1)=\sec^2x\tan^2x+\sec^2x$. Now you can integrate?

In general: Whenever you have an EVEN power of secant, the idea is to "peel off" one $\sec^2x$ and convert all other $\sec^2x$ terms into $tan^2x+1$ terms. It's a little annoying to work out the parenthesis on $(\tan^2x+1)^n$ but that's just algebra. What is going to happen is that you will end up with tangent terms that all are accompanied with a $\sec^2x$ terms, so they are ready to be integrated with the power rule.

Answer (score 1):

For this problem in particular, I would automatically do what @TheIntegrator did, but in general we can find 
$$I_n=\int\sec^nx\ dx$$
$$I_n=\int\sec^{n-2}x\sec^2x\ dx$$
$$I_n=\int(\tan^2x+1)^{n-2}\sec^2x\ dx$$
Applying the substitution $u=\tan x$ gives
$$I_n=\int(u^2+1)^{n-2}du$$
Assuming that $n\geq2$ is an **even** integer, we can expand our integrand into a series using the binomial formula:
$$(a+b)^m=\sum_{k=0}^m{m\choose k}a^{m-k}b^k$$
Plugging in $a=u^2$, $b=1$, and $m=n-2$ gives
$$I_n=\int\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{n-2\choose k}(u^2)^{n-k-2}du$$
$$I_n=\int\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{n-2\choose k}u^{2n-2k-4}du$$
Cleverly interchanging the $\sum$ and $\int$ signs,
$$I_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{n-2\choose k}\int u^{2n-2k-4}du$$
Integrating $u^{2n-2k-4}$ and plugging in gives 
$$I_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{n-2\choose k}\frac{u^{2n-2k-3}}{2n-2k-3}$$
$$I_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{n-2\choose k}\frac{(\tan x)^{2n-2k-3}}{2n-2k-3}+C$$
Keep in mind that this formula only works for positive even values of $n$. If you want to know a general formula that works for all $n$, I can show you, but it's a bit more involved.

Comment: As I have developed quite significantly in the past couple years, I would not be opposed to seeing the general form \forall n if you are still willing